# how i blend the gradient bg with my looped images using tailwind

Tags: frontend, hover, tailwind-css

i tried like this, i tried all blend modes, changing the order of both images, changing opacity on hover but still clueless

```
<div className="grid grid-cols-3 px-{100}">
          {gallery.map((el, i) => {
            return (
              <>
                <div className="group object-cover">
                  <p className="items-center text-2xl text-brand-primary transition-all duration-500 opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-100 absolute flex pl-[32px] pt-[411px]">{gallery[i].title}</p>
                  <div className='mix-blend-add'>
                    <img className="bg-auto absolute  opacity:0 h-[57%] group-hover:opacity-100 h-full" src='/rectangle.svg' />
                    <img className="duration-500 transition-all opacity:90 group-hover:opacity-50 delay-100 text-white" src={gallery[i].imgSrc} />
                    {/* <div class="absolute -z-10 bg-gradient-to-t from-white via-gray-900 to-black h-[70vh] lg:h-[80vh]" /> */}
                  </div>
                </div>
```

I want to make my picture look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3fuh.png) when i hover
instead i got this [the first picture is on hover, the second not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvWtq.png)